# Windows Phone 7 unit tests from command line

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, command-line

I need to run my Windows Phone 7 unit tests from the command line, as in, not having to interact with any GUI elements. Is this possible?

EDIT:
I am using the silverlight testing framework here http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using MSTEST for your unit tests (you didn't specify), then yes, just use the [mstest.exe command line interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, however, whenever I try to run mstest with testcontainer set to the dll, I get an error that says "could not load file or assembly System.Windows" I'm stumped as to how do I properly use mstest for windows phone?